# Server Access denied when changing the admin password

Tags: python, django, ubuntu-12.04, odoo

This is my first project in openerp. I have completed the installation of server from [here](https://doc.openerp.com/install/linux/server/#openerp-server-installation)
and the postgresql installation from [here](https://doc.openerp.com/install/linux/postgres/#installation-postgresql-server)

After these i run the project using localhost

In setting/user
I'm getting the following error when trying to change the password for the admin .

```
OpenERP Server Error
    Client Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/addons/web/http.py", line 204, in dispatch
    response["result"] = method(self, **self.params)
    File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1037, in load_needaction
    return req.session.model('ir.ui.menu').get_needaction_data(menu_ids, req.context)
    File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 42, in proxy
    result = self.proxy.execute_kw(self.session._db, self.session._uid, self.session._password, self.model, method, args, kw)
    File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 30, in proxy_method
    result = self.session.send(self.service_name, method, *args)
    File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 97, in send
    raise xmlrpclib.Fault('AccessDenied', openerp.tools.ustr(e))

    Server Access denied.
```

I'm also getting the same error when clicking on the button '*Send reset password link by email*'.

But in both cases the password is being updated successfully.

Why am I getting these error? Thanks in advance..